# setting the hours value in date time picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grails, datetimepicker

I have added jQuery, JQuery-ui and some JQuery add-on called the datetime picker to my grails application, everything works fine, there is only some issue with the hours value that it does not change it keeps staying HH.

[can not insert picture]

So, as you can see the HH value does not change, i have tried the formatting tips and nothing seems to be working, where did i fail ?

P.S : JQuery libraries are installed as a plugin.

Comment: "So, as you can see the HH value does not change" , Did you forgot to share the jsfiddle link?

Comment: Okey, solved it,i had to put time = "'hh-mm'" instead of time = "'HH-mm'" in the Config.groovy file ! Thanks SAM

Comment: it was not really a javascript problem, it was grails configuration problem, thanks anyway!